# Mercurial: push creates new remote head on branch

Tags: mercurial

I've read probably 15 other threads with the same problem, but every solution has been "try pulling and merging", which I've done several times.

Anyway, we have a main branch called "develop". I don't have permission to directly push to this branch. When I do `hg push --new-branch`, I get the message:

```
abort: push creates new remote head 872f21c639d0 on branch 'develop'!
```

Somehow, I guess I must have done changes to the develop branch without me knowing. So I though that **only** pushing my branch would work (as mercurial pushes all branches by default). But calling `hg push -r . --new-branch` gives me the same error. Why?

When I call `hg heads develop` I get the following:

```
changeset:   42407:872f21c639d0
branch:      develop
parent:      42300:f25b068a235d
parent:      42313:1b2c4907cd9a
user:        ---
date:        Tue Jun 25 09:30:41 2019 +0200
summary:     Merged

changeset:   42402:05374ad32e87
branch:      develop
parent:      42396:5ab53c02c668
parent:      42401:552e0a676dad
user:        ---
date:        Wed Jun 26 06:10:22 2019 +0000
summary:     ~some message~
```

Okay, strange, I have two heads. I tried to `hg strip` one of the heads on `develop` but then all the changes I did on MY branch disappeared, and there were still two heads (another head). Any idea on how to fix this?

**EDIT**: Output of `hg log -G -b develop`

```
o    changeset:   42407:05374ad32e87
|\   branch:      develop
| :  parent:      42396:5ab53c02c668
| :  parent:      42401:552e0a676dad
| :  user:        P K 
| :  date:        Wed Jun 26 06:10:22 2019 +0000
| :  summary:     Merged in ... (pull request #3700)
| :
| \
| :\
| : \
| : :\
| : : \
| : : :\
| : : : \
| : : : :\
| : +-------o  changeset:   42402:872f21c639d0
| : : : : : |  branch:      develop
| : : : : : |  parent:      42300:f25b068a235d
| : : : : : |  parent:      42313:1b2c4907cd9a
| : : : : : |  user:        Me
| : : : : : |  date:        Tue Jun 25 09:30:41 2019 +0200
| : : : : : |  summary:     Merged
| : : : : : |
o : : : : : |    changeset:   42396:5ab53c02c668
|\ \ \ \ \ \ \   branch:      develop
| : : : : : : :  parent:      42393:8e323e33732f
| : : : : : : :  parent:      42394:8bc5afa596e5
| : : : : : : :  user:        M L
| : : : : : : :  date:        Tue Jun 25 16:06:05 2019 +0000
| : : : : : : :  summary:     Merged in d... (pull request #3673)
| : : : : : : :
| \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| :\ \ \ \ \ \ \
| : \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| : :\ \ \ \ \ \ \
| : : \ \ \ \ \ \ \
| : : :\ \ \ \ \ \ \
o-----------------+-+    changeset:   42393:8e323e33732f
:\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \   branch:      develop
: : : : : : : : : : : |  parent:      42384:bc2542ffb64e
: : : : : : : : : : : |  parent:      42390:61241d9fc224
: : : : : : : : : : : |  user:        M L 
: : : : : : : : : : : |  date:        Tue Jun 25 15:25:11 2019 +0000
: : : : : : : : : : : |  summary:     Merged in ... (pull request #3706)
: : : : : : : : : : : |
: : : : : : : +-----o |    changeset:   42384:bc2542ffb64e
: : : : : : : : : : |\ \   branch:      develop
: : : : : : : : : : | : |  parent:      42381:701c99b3e133
: : : : : : : : : : | : |  parent:      42383:b9c8fa2d8f00
: : : : : : : : : : | : |  user:        P A
: : : : : : : : : : | : |  date:        Tue Jun 25 14:25:54 2019 +0000
: : : : : : : : : : | : |  summary:     Merged in ... (pull request #3689)
: : : : : : : : : : | : |
: +-----------+-----o : |  changeset:   42381:701c99b3e133
```

Comment: try to look at it using TortoiseHg revision graph (or `hg log -G -b develop`). it could provide a better overview of what's been going on with that branch.

Comment: I can post the output, but it doesn't help me at all :/

Comment: When you strip **only one changeset** (second HEAD), it's parent become HEAD again. You have to eliminate the whole *anonymous branch* in `develop` (from branchpoint): with strip/merge/rebase

Comment: And another note: `--new-branch` will allow push and create **new named branch** on push-target, second head of existing branch not covered of this option. Additional head of existing branch on push can be created only by `--force` option (when|if it's needed)

Comment: `hg log -r only(42402, 42407)` will show full still not merged into "good" head diverged history of `develop`